# Excluding the mime type from Android manifest file

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using android sharing functionality by putting this code in androidmainfest.xml

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
```

In my application currently i do not support handling of "plain/text". Otherwise i support all other kind of mime types. is there any way i can mention the type in the manifest.xml which i wan't to exclude from handling rather than mentioning all the types which i handle.

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: **"Otherwise i support all other kind of mime types."** - So you support all mime types such as every video and audio format plus all possible document types etc etc but you don't support plain text???

Comment: yeah because applications like Youtube send the video url as plain/text which i don't support in my app..is it possible to exclude one specific type the xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

Propably there is a better solution for blacklisting mimetypes like "text/plain". In my app I also accept all files (for storage purpose) but don't want to receive just Links of dropbox-files or whatever (who are sent as text/plain).

Maybe use a whitelist and suppress textfiles at all:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
  <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
  <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
  <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
  <data android:mimeType="model/*" />
  <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
  <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</action>
```

...regarding to http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml there are just those few mime-groups available.