# How to make a kind of blacklist for some mime-types for Android application?

Tags: android, mime-types, intentfilter, blacklist

In [our Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jetico.bestcrypt) we need to catch an ACTION_SEND intent from third-party apps with arbitrary mime-type

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

except of .apk files, **i.e. we need blacklist for .apk extension. Is it possible?** It seems the answer is ["No way"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945600/excluding-the-mime-type-from-android-manifest-file), but I have two apps installed on my device, which definitely solve this problem. They are called for file with arbitrary extension [lumix.p&z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti34S.png) opened from DropBox app

and are not called with .apk [oi.filemanager.apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu0Cr.png). **How does it possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems the answer is "No way"

There is no way to specify a blacklist in the manifest.

> I have two apps installed on my device, which definitely solve this problem

Dropbox is using a MIME type on the `lumix.p&z` request that those office apps have registered for. Dropbox is using a MIME type on the `oi.filemanager.apk` request that those office apps have not registered for. No blacklist is required. What *is* required is for Dropbox to have its own algorithms, possibly implemented on its servers, to guess an appropriate MIME type.

Comment: There is no such an extension - .p&z. I have wrote it just as an example of any extension. Therefore, those office apps have registered for any extension. But, from other side, those office apps have not registered for .apk extension. Obviously, we have a contradiction here. How can it be?

Comment: @isabsent: "Therefore, those office apps have registered for any extension" -- no. Dropbox is using other techniques to deduce a MIME type, such as looking at the contents of the file. Or, Dropbox is using `application/octet-stream` or another generic MIME type, which those apps happen to have registered for.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! Probably, you are right. I will mark your answer as a solution after some time if no other assumptions will be made.

Comment: @isabsent: Note that you can use apps like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majeur.applicationsinfo) to examine the manifest of the apps on your device, so you can see what those two office apps have.